# Unit test : assembly missing but don't see which one

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to make 3 unit tests but I have a little problem.

Visual Studio says that an assembly reference is missing, but I don't see which one.

Here's my code :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TestsUnitairesSaisieHeures
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestsSaisieHeures
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void NumeroSemaineTest()
        {
            //1 - Initialisation des variables
            DateTime DateTest = new DateTime(2016,11,3);
            bool expected = false;           
            bool actual;

            //2 - Appel de la méthode à tester
            actual = SaisieHeures.NumeroSemaine(DateTest);

            //3 - Vérification du résultat
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Vérifiez l\'exactitude de cette méthode de test.");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetWeekDaysOfWeekFromTest()
        {
            int weekNumberTest = 33;
            bool expected = false;
            bool actual;

            actual = SaisieHeures.GetWeekDaysOfWeekFrom(weekNumberTest);

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Vérifiez l\'exactitude de cette méthode de test.");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void FirstDateOfWeekISO8601Test()
        {
            int yearTest = 2016;
            int weekOfYearTest = 44;
            bool expected = false;
            bool actual;

            actual = SaisieHeures.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(yearTest, weekOfYearTest);

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Vérifiez l\'exactitude de cette méthode de test.");
        }

        // Pour exécuter du code avant d'exécuter le premier test dans la classe
        [ClassInitialize()]
        public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
        {
        }

        // Pour exécuter du code après que tous les tests ont été exécutés dans une classe 
        [ClassCleanup()] public static void MyClassCleanup()
        {
        }

        // Pour exécuter du code avant d'exécuter chaque test 
        [TestInitialize()]
        public void MyTestInitialize()
        {
        }

        // Pour exécuter du code après que chaque test a été exécuté 
        [TestCleanup()]
        public void MyTestCleanup()
        {
        } 
    }
}
```

And the error I'm getting

> CS0234 Test C# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I put in reference my solution but I still have the same problem.

Do you see where the problem is?

Comment: show the error message

Comment: CS0234  Test C# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Most probably your Unit Test project has lower .NET version than target projects. Right click on your project and properties and match .NET version of your targets.

Comment: It's when i want to do : SaisieHeures.NameOfMyMethodInTheOtherProject()

Comment: @Teomanshipahi The .Net version are exactly the same in my unit test project and my webform project : Framework .Net 4.5.2

Comment: SaisieHeures should have some dependencies which are not satisfied. Can it be System.Web, System.Net etc?

Comment: @Teomanshipahi I've already tried ; same problem :(

Comment: what's the namespace of 'SaisieHeures',

Answer (score 2):

You are propably missing the 'using [namespace of SaisieHeures];' at the top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved ; that's because the name of my solution have the same name than my class.
I'm forced to put : SaisieHeures.SaisieHeures.MethodName()

Future Lesson : Avoid to put the same name.

Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the answers.

Comment: Since this solved your problem, you should mark it as the correct solution.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days to do it :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize there was a delay